# Recalling an instance variable in a virtual attribute with Ruby

Tags: ruby, instance-variables

So I am just starting to make my way through The Pragmatic Bookself's, "[Programming Ruby 1.9 (3rd Edition)](http://pragprog.com/titles/ruby3/programming-ruby-1-9)" and I've come across some code that I need a little clarification on.

If you own the book, it's in Chapter 3's, "Classes, Objects, and Variables," specifically in the section about virtual attributes.

Basically, a class is defined with an initializer that sets a couple of instance variables, one of which is `@price`. That variable has an accessor / mutator created with attr_accessor like so:

```
attr_accessor :price
```

That class also has a virtual attribute called, `price_in_cents` which simply returns the value from this line:

```
Integer(price*100 + 0.5)
```

Now my question is why is `price` in the virtual attribute not prefixed with an `@`? It is clearly dealing with an instance variable. Executing the code without the `@` works just the same as with; why is that?

P.S. Sorry for not just posting the code wholesale—given that this is a question about code in a book, I wasn't sure what legal right I'd have to post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a receiverless message send.

In Ruby, the receiver `self` is implicit: you can leave it out if you want to. So, `price` is basically the same as `self.price` (ignoring access restrictions).

In other words, it's calling the method `price` you defined with `attr_accessor`.

Comment: So this is just done to ensure that the `price` variable is accessed through the class provided accessor (in case it isn't simply returning `@price`)?

Comment: @Jean-Charles: Yep. Basically, it's the fundamental principle of object-orientation: *everything is a message send*. Accessing a variable is *not* a message send, thus not object-oriented, and should be avoided if possible. This buys you *representation independence*: the `price_in_cents` method is completely ignorant of how prices are represented, which allows you to change the representation (say, pull it from a databsse instead of an instance variable) without changing any code.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily confirm that that two references (`price` and `@price`) point to the same objects:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

class MyPrice < Object
  attr_accessor :price

  def initialize(price = 0)
    @price = price
  end

  def price_in_cents
    Integer(price * 100 + 0.5)
  end

  def objects
    puts "@price.object_id: #{@price.object_id}"
    puts "price.object_id:  #{price.object_id}"
  end
end

p = MyPrice.new(150)
p.objects
puts "price in cents: #{p.price_in_cents}"
```

Which produces:

```
# ./price.rb 
@price.object_id: 301
price.object_id:  301
price in cents: 15000
```

The fact that `price` and `@price` both have an object id of 301 shows you that they are both references to a single object.

Comment: Except `price` *isn't* a reference to an object, it's a message send.

Answer (score 0):

This question was posted years back but just in case anybody is running into similar issues like the example on top.

I don't think self.price has anything to do with attr_accessor, self.price only applies to the class where attr_accessor becomes a shortcut for instance variable. You don't need to input the '@' in front of the attr_accessor because it acts as a shortcut for your setters and getters if you are familiar to Java. Part of Ruby's easy going way of getting things done faster more eloquently.